# Как с помощью regexp найти закрывающие теги, перед которыми нет открывающих?

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения

Выражение для примера: `<strong> lorem [[ipsum dolor sit </strong>amet]]`

Нужно составить regexp для выделения внутри `[[...]]` закрывающих тегов, перед которыми нет открывающих. Я пытался сделать вот так `(?<!\[\[.+?<strong>.+?(?=<\/strong>))<\/strong>`, но он выделяет и те закрывающие теги, которые вне скобок `[[...]]`. Например здесь это выражение выделит оба `</strong>`:

```
<strong> lorem</strong> [[ipsum dolor sit </strong>amet]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ. Следующее регулярное выражение находит закрывающие теги, перед которыми нет открывающих, в рамках `[[...]]`:

```
(\[\[[^\][]*?)(?<!([^\][]*?<strong>[^\][]*?(?=<\/strong>)))<\/strong>
```

https://regex101.com/r/t8hNpA/2

И вот "вторая половина", которая уже не относится напрямую к вопросу, но решает задачу в инверсивном виде. Следующее выражение находит **открывающие** теги, после которых нет закрывающих, в рамках `[[...]]`:

```
(?<=\[\[[^\][]*?)<strong>(?!(?<=<strong>)[^\][]*?<\/strong>)([^\][]*?\]\])
```